# "Capture ... on the strength" as What does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In the United States, the supposed citadel of free market enterprise, a wealthy real estate magnate has captured the White House on the strength of his appeal as a supposed champion of blue-collar workers.

<sup>([NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/17/business/dealbook/world-economic-forum-davos-china-xi-globalization.html))</sup>

I guess it means that this magnate feels that the white house is putting pressure on his appeal, which means that his appeal won't be approved, and this indicates the government champions the blue-collar workers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is not correct.  "A wealthy real estate magnate" = "Donald Trump".

The entire sentence is about how Trump won the presidency, ironically by *appealing to* (asking for the votes of) blue collar workers -- despite that fact that Trump is not even remotely "working class".